# How to add another value to a given row and column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I've been struggling with one problem for two days that I have with Python and the Pandas package. I am creating a dataframe with filtered data from another csv and then want to export it to csv again. However, I have a problem because I do not know how to add another value to a specific cell without removing the previous one so that it looks more or less like this in CSV.
So that I could add this letter b to the second column and the first row where the letter a already exists

[image]

Comment: Can you please add [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) outling input/output and the code(if) you have written so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code
It edits all of the rows if you want
else you want to edit just first row you can remove for loop and use i=0

```py
for i in df.index:
  if df['B'][i].find('a')>=0:
    df['B'][i] += ', b'
```

Comment: This is how it solves my problem. I didn't know it would be that simple. I tried with add, append functions.
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: these methods are for python list not dataframe

Answer (score 1):

```
df_10 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['xx', '--- bios ---', 'yy', 'zz', '--- os ---'],'B': ['rat', '', 'winter', 'host','']})
```

I create such a data frame as add to column A and line 2, for example the value "new"

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach the problem:

#### Creating example dataframe

- Code:

  ```markdown
  df = pd.DataFrame(
      data={
          'A': [1, 2, 3],
          'B': ['a', 'a', 'b'],
      }
  )
  ```
- Result

  ```markdown
  df

      A   B
  0   1   a
  1   2   a
  2   3   b
  ```

#### Applying function to add character (with comma) only on the rows that meet a condition

- Method: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html
- Code:

  ```markdown
  # Condition: the character 'a' has to be present

  df['B'].apply(lambda x: x + ', b' if 'a' in x else x)
  ```
- Result:

  ```markdown
  df

      A   B
  0   1   a, b
  1   2   a, b
  2   3   b
  ```

This will work for the entire 2nd column (in this example, column ‘B’).

If you’d like to apply this rule only to a specific row of the dataframe, I would only add the following:

#### Applying function to add character (with comma) only on the rows that meet a condition

- Code:

  ```markdown
  # Condition: the character 'a' has to be present on a selecteed row

  row = 0 ## row where you'd like to apply the change

  df.loc[row, ['B']] = df.loc[row, ['B']].apply(lambda x: x + ', b' if 'a' in x else x)
  ```
- Result:

  ```markdown
  df

      A   B
  0   1   a, b
  1   2   a
  2   3   b
  ```

Hope this solutions helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is very very faster and better

```py
def f(s):
    if s.find('a')>=0:
        return s+', b'
    return s
df['B']=df['B'].apply(func=f)
```